# Reading From a Text File and Executing What You Find

Tags: batch-file, execute

I can't figure out how to do what it says in the title. I have a text file apple.txt with:

```
set apple=7
```

and a file saved as a batch with

```
findstr /v "zzzzzzzzzzz" apple.txt
```

and when I run the batch file it displays "set apple=7" instead of actually setting the variable apple to 7. I'm assuming `findstr` adds an `echo` before each line but I don't know. I used the CMD with findstr /? but I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (apple.txt) DO %%i
```

should do that

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are doing with the find string.  But if you have a file named out.txt with the following code:

```
dir
```

And from the command line you type:

```
cmd < out.txt
```

The contents of the file is piped into the command line processor.

Comment: Does it have to be out.txt?

Comment: So If I had apple.txt with the code dir set apple=7 and in the batch file I had cmd < apple.txt would it set apple equal to seven in that batch file?

Comment: Any file name works.  Yes and no.  The setting is done in the shell that is executing the file, not the shell you are typing into.